# How to prevent cheese and certain other products from stinking up my fridge?

Tags: storage-method, cheese, smell, pate

Certain food products have a very strong odor, 
that may not seem annoying at all when I buy them,
but become very much apparent after I keep them in the fridge for a few hours.

For example these kind products:

- roquefort cheese
- liver pâté
- pretty much any kind of meat pâté

My fridge is quite new, kept clean, and normally doesn't smell, only when I buy these products. I don't keep these products for a long time, I always eat them within 2-3 days,
but I cannot prevent the bad smell from lasting about a week,
after which it naturally dissipates.

I tried wrapping the products in double-bags and inside sealed plastic boxes but it didn't make a big difference. I also keep a few trays of baking soda in the fridge, but that doesn't seem to help much either. What else can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Hello @janos and welcome to Seasoned Advice! The first thing that comes to mind would be to first wrap your food items tightly in plastic wrap and then vacuum seal them. However, if you open and close them frequently that could be a pain. But, if you on are only keeping the items 2 - 3 days, it could work.

That said, plastic can absorb odors and allow them to be detected outside of the packaging. I think the best solution would be glass. As always, for freshness, wrap the food in plastic wrap first and then store in glass. Glass should not let any odors escape.

An idea of what I'm talking about is pictured below. You can find a full description  [here](http://www.soap.com/p/glasslock-kinetic-go-green-square-storage-set-3pc-30-oz-268403?site=CA&sku=ZPV-6630&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc_S&utm_campaign=GooglePLA&utm_content=pla&ca_sku=ZPV-6630&ca_gpa=pla&ca_kw=&CAWELAID=500001850000514333&kpid=ZPV-6630) .

[image]

Comment: Glass! Thank you Cindy, I'll definitely try that. Are these boxes tightly sealed? Can't really tell from the picture

Comment: Yes. They are airtight and watertight. This brand has a variety of sizes to choose from and there are other brands available.